# round QDecDouble value with an accuracy of up to two characters

Tags: c++, qt

I'm use [qdecimal](https://github.com/semihc/qdecimal) library.
It is necessary to round the number with an accuracy of up to two characters.

```
1.55555 => 1.56
```

Now I do it this way

```
QDecDouble dd(1.55555);
dd.multiply(QDecDouble(100));
dd = dd.toIntegralValue(DEC_ROUND_HALF_UP);
dd.divide(QDecDouble(100));
```

Is there a more optimal way of doing this rounding?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for you or not. I've used [`QString::number`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6).

**Here's an example:**

```
#include <qDebug>

int main( void )
{
    const double n1 { 1.55555 };

    const auto n2 = QString::number( n1, 'f', 2 ).toDouble();

    qDebug() << "n1:" << n1;
    qDebug() << "n2:" << n2;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
n1: 1.55555
n2: 1.56
```